# function rand() codeblocks doesnt compile

Tags: random, codeblocks

im trying to compile this code in codeblocks but doesnt work, i dont know what it is produced error

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cmath>
#include<ctime>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
const int NUMLANZ=1000;

int caras=0,cruces=0,i;
double volado,porcaras,porcruces;

srand(time(NULL));
for(i=1;1<=NUMLANZ; i++)
{
    volado= ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX));
    if(volado>0.5)
        caras=caras+1;
    else
        cruces=cruces+1;
}
porcaras=(caras/double (NUMLANZ))*100;
porcruces=(cruces/ double(NUMLANZ))*100;
cout<<"\nCaras salio  "<<porcaras<<" por ciento de las veces";
cout<<"\nCruces salio  "<<porcruces<<"  por ciento de las veces";

return 0;
}
```

im new in c++ code, i dont know if the compile produced error becaue this code was copied from c++ book study so its strange that this code doesnt work

Comment: Even if you don't know how to use a debugger, just add cout statements after some lines and see where it crashes or gives you errors....

Answer (score 1):

The loop will never terminate because the literal constant 1 is always less that `NUMLANZ`.

Compare:

```
    for( i = 1; 1 <= NUMLANZ; i++ )
                ^
```

with

```
    for( i = 1; i <= NUMLANZ; i++ )
                ^
```

Note also that it is more conventional for loop counters to start from zero:

```
    for( i = 0; i < NUMLANZ; i++ )
```

In this case it makes no difference other then one less character, but if you are using `i` to index an array for example, it is critical.